# Bonobo Git Server при переходе в репозиторий ошибка 404

Tags: git, bonobo

Такая ситуация,создал в IIS Manager каталог,дал права и проверил доступность,все гуд.
Настраивал по этой инструкции
[инструкция](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313564/)

создал репозиторий **http://localhost:8081/BonoboGit/mobile.git** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда нажимаю на **http://localhost:8081/BonoboGit/mobile.git**
то открывается страница:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]